# Fetch value of JSON response in BPEL variable

Tags: javascript, soa, weblogic12c, bpel

I am trying to fetch the value of an attribute returned by a rest service in JSON in SOA 12c BPEL assig activity using javascript.

The response returned by the rest service is as below:

```
<messages>
<InputVar>
      <json>{

}</json>
   </InputVar>
<OutputVar>
      <json>{
   "response": [
      {
         "local_product_version": 1,
         "local_product_id": 1
      },
      {
         "local_product_version": 1,
         "local_product_id": 2
      },
      {
         "local_product_version": 1,
         "local_product_id": 3
      }
   ]
}</json>
   </OutputVar>
</messages>
```

When I am using the assign activity to capture the response attribute value, the value of the variable is coming as below:

```
   <id xmlns:def="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="def:string">org.mozilla.javascript.Undefined@41c96386</id>
```

Instead of the above org.mozilla.javascript.Undefined@41c96386, I need the value of the attribute as shown below:

```
<id xmlns:def="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="def:string">1</id>
```

I tried with the below javascript syntax already but no luck:

1. ```
   OutputVar.message.data.response.local_product_version
   ```
  2.

```
OutputVar.response[0].local_product_version
```

Could someone please suggest how I can achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just extract the object from json response 'manually':

```
const txt = `
<messages>
<InputVar>
      <json>{

}</json>
   </InputVar>
<OutputVar>
      <json>{
   "response": [
      {
         "local_product_version": 1,
         "local_product_id": 1
      },
      {
         "local_product_version": 1,
         "local_product_id": 2
      },
      {
         "local_product_version": 1,
         "local_product_id": 3
      }
   ]
}</json>
   </OutputVar>
</messages>
`;

const RE = /\<OutputVar\>\s*\<json\>(.*)\<\/json\>\s*\<\/OutputVar\>/s;

const result = RE.exec(txt);

if (result) {
  const json = result[1];
  const obj = JSON.parse(json)
  console.log(obj)
}
```

so, you got:

```
// {
//   response: [
//     { local_product_version: 1, local_product_id: 1 },
//     { local_product_version: 1, local_product_id: 2 },
//     { local_product_version: 1, local_product_id: 3 }
//   ]
// }
```

Now you got it as a regular JS object and can get from it whatever is required, including `local_product_version`

Then you can use it to make the desired result string:

```
const local_product_version = obj.response[0].local_product_version;
const result = `<id xmlns:def="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="def:string">${local_product_version}</id>`

console.log(result);

// <id xmlns:def="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="def:string">1</id>
```

Comment: I need to do it in SOA so if you could tell me how to do in assign activity it would be more helpful.

Comment: I mean, if you can run some JS, then you are able to produce desired result by yourself. Let's say you need a string that is looking like `<id xmlns:def="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="def:string">1</id>` . Then you make such a string inserting proper `local_product_version` value inside - in place of `1`

Comment: const local_product_version = <see full code in above answer to get it> ; const result = `<id xmlns:def="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="def:string">${local_product_version}</id>`; - and now you get the string you are looking for.

Comment: Otherwise, I can't tell how to do it in specific environment of SOA, sorry.

Comment: hi All, i want to append set of JSON objects in JSON array how to do that in BPEL javascript activity? can any one help